# Any app to know what an app is doing, checking, creating, and etc.?

Tags: windows, security

As you may know, some apps doing, checking, creating somethings in the background that we don't see and know. Is there any app that can show us what is doing, checking, creating, etc. an app?

e.g. the an app that show us what is going on the regdit.exe when we run or install another app? or what or which files is creating or running or manipulating?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot of ProcessMonitor]

[ProcessMonitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) by Microsoft (originally by Sysinternals, they were bought by MS) shows file, registry, network and process activity and has filters so you can set it to just show activity due to one process. It is free and powerful. It comes with a help file (.chm)

The author demonstrates it's use in [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2016/BRK4028) at 24m. You can find extensive tutorials elsewhere such as [this one by Lowell Vanderpool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL1msF9-bnk) or [this one by Scott Hanselman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjKNx41Ubxw).